# JSP page not rendering

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

which i'm trying to render in as Java application running as Spring Boot App deployed on Tomcat. I just see the above text as it is in the browser.

I think the issue is same as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412623/jsp-not-rendering-properly-in-tomcat). But can't understand how it is solved.

Comment: what web application server are you using? Tomcat?

Comment: Yes. Application is deployed on tomcat.

Comment: Did you deploy manually in tomcat webapps? If it yes, add `servlet-api.jar` in your webapps folder and start the tomcat again.

Comment: Added servlet-api through maven pom.xml and restarted server. Issue still exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you deploy your project in tomcat webapps directory .
2. add servlet-api.jar file in lib directory or if you are use mavan then ensure that your jar files are downloaded or not.
3. restart your tomcat server and after hit your jsp page.

Comment: javax.servlet-api.jar is present inside Maven dependencies. Issue still exists.