# Enable JSP in Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have setup Tomcat version 7.0.65 and I am trying to open a .jsp file. What I get as a result is something in the line of:

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<div id="body-0" class="body">
    <div class="body-content">
        <h1 class="title solid">What is Delivery IQ?</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U6P8GxPCbyc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And not the actual site. Does anyone know what do I have to do in order to get it working?

Comment: how do you try to "open" it?

Comment: Have you deployed your project into Tomcat?

Comment: If you locate the *.jsp file on your system. Right-click on it; choose "Open with" and select an internet browser client {Internet Exporer, Fire Fox, Chrome etc.}.

Comment: I have changed this in the server.xml file:

<code><Host name="localhost"  appBase="C:\website"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</code>
So now Tomcat see the project folder instead of the default one. This way I am able to deploy it.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic I have tried what you suggested and I get the same result. What I am trying to do is to open the file using http://localhost/.....

Comment: What IDE are you using, and why don't you just use the integration of Tomcat that's most likely offered by that IDE?

Comment: I am using Eclipse, but I also want to just launch everything manually.

Comment: @Aris could you confirm the extension of the file you are opening is it *.jsp?

Comment: Yeap it's a .jsp file alright. My problem is that Tomcat seems to be unable to properly display .jsp files. I do not know if this has to do with a configuration or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412623/jsp-not-rendering-properly-in-tomcat?rq=1

Comment: Is tomcat up? On which port is listening? Try deploying a simple html page and try accessing it via browser at the address localhost/example.html. If it doesn't go then maybe your tomcat is down. How do you start the server?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile all the application and deploy to the Tomcat. [Please read this link.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)

Also you could read [enter link description here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118656466) this could make it clear in first of the chapters.

Without RTFM you are just blindly clicking.